# Java Class.forName giving ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database and for that i need to load a secure-driver from my organization. I try to load it like :

```
Class.forName("mycompany.jdbc.driver.SecureDriver");
```

When this is executed i get the following error :

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        com.mycompany.dpx.dependencytree.DbUtils.establishConnection(DbUtils.java:53)
        com.mycompany.dpx.dependencytree.DbUtils.saveObject(DbUtils.java:109)
        com.mycompany.dpx.dependencytree.ModuleToModuleDependencyGraphFactory.getDependencyGraph(ModuleToModuleDependencyGraphFactory.java:294)
        com.mycompany.dpx.MVCSuperController.renderAsinRoute(MVCSuperController.java:576)
        com.mycompany.dpx.MVCSuperController.renderAsin(MVCSuperController.java:1028)
        com.mycompany.dpx.GenericController.renderRemotePPD(GenericController.java:76)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.spring.handlers.horizonte.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:476)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.spring.handlers.horizonte.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handleRequest(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:467)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.spring.handlers.horizonte.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:431)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.spring.handlers.horizonte.AnnotationTopControllerHandlerAdapter.doHandle(AnnotationTopControllerHandlerAdapter.java:27)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.spring.handlers.horizonte.AbstractTopControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(AbstractTopControllerHandlerAdapter.java:116)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        com.mycompany.dpx.filter.DetailPageResponseTimeoutFilter.doFilterInternal(DetailPageResponseTimeoutFilter.java:46)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        com.mycompany.dpx.filter.MarketplaceIdFilter.doFilterInternal(MarketplaceIdFilter.java:45)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        com.mycompany.membership.filter.FilterLogic.execute(FilterLogic.java:98)
        com.mycompany.membership.horizonte.filter.HorizonteMembershipLoadingFilter.doFilterInternal(HorizonteMembershipLoadingFilter.java:27)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.servlet.filters.NoHttpSessionFilter.doFilterInternal(NoHttpSessionFilter.java:24)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.servlet.filters.PageDecoratorFilter.doFilterInternal(PageDecoratorFilter.java:104)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.servlet.filters.SanitizeFilter.doFilterInternal(SanitizeFilter.java:41)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.servlet.filters.QueryLogFilter.doFilterInternal(QueryLogFilter.java:122)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.mycompany.servlet.filters.DevFilter.doFilter(DevFilter.java:54)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.mycompany.servlet.filters.MarketplaceOverrideFilter.doFilterInternal(MarketplaceOverrideFilter.java:66)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.mycompany.servlet.filters.Log4jFilter.doFilterInternal(Log4jFilter.java:31)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.mycompany.servlet.filters.IsInternalFilter.doFilterInternal(IsInternalFilter.java:49)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.servlet.filters.RenderingWaitFilter.doFilterInternal(RenderingWaitFilter.java:55)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.raw.server.servlet.filters.RawFilter.doFilterInternal(RawFilter.java:104)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        com.mycompany.horizonte.servlet.filters.ServletObjectsHolderFilter.doFilter(ServletObjectsHolderFilter.java:62)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:427)
        com.mycompany.dpx.filter.RemoteHeadersFilter.doFilterInternal(RemoteHeadersFilter.java:104)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        com.mycompany.dpx.filter.SecureRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(SecureRequestFilter.java:38)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        mycompany.actiontrace.generation.servlet.StorageBindingFilter.doFilter(StorageBindingFilter.java:40)
```

I am not able to figure what is wrong and how to correct it.

If some info is missing don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Please provide full stacktrace.

Comment: how `mycompany.jdbc.driver.SecureDriver` look like?

Comment: @YCF_L no idea actually i am told to load it when accessing database. It provides a secure access to the DB. Also i can't provide it code since its an internal driver. I can tell you that it implements `Driver` class

Comment: @Shinchan I have edited the question with the stack trace available to me the rest is just shown as `...` even to me.

Comment: ok can u try without loading your driver?

Comment: u mean the default driver?

Comment: sorry i mean without calling this line `Class.forName("mycompany.jdbc.driver.SecureDriver");`

Comment: I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for <DB_ADDRESS>` this is the Exception thrown when i remove the driver.

Comment: You should contact the team within your company that maintains that `SecureDriver`, it looks like something is wrong in that driver, or you are doing something wrong. We can't know nor help you **because this is a proprietary driver**.